# How to prove that this function will converge to $1$?

Tags: calculus

I have an assignment for tomorrow that ask me to prove that the sequence/function

$f(x) =\begin{cases}\dfrac x2\quad\quad\quad\text{if } x\text{ is even}\\3x+1\quad\;\text{if }x\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$

(where $x$ is a natural number)

will converge to $1$.

I have tried by hand and it seems to work but I have no idea where to start.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by it converges to 1? $f$ is just a function. What if $f$ is not an integer?

Comment: @copper.hat Probably the limit when $x$ goes to $0$

Comment: @Aram: What if $x$ is neither odd not even?

Comment: @copper.hat x is a natural number

Comment: The edit seems to say it's a sequence, $f : \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ I guess. But then it doesn't seem to converge to $1$ at all.

Comment: @Platehead do you have a counter example? it seems to work with everything I tried?

Comment: I have no idea what you could possibly mean by converges to 1 in this case.

Comment: @copper.hat for example for x=5, f(5)=16, f(16)=8, f(8)=4, f(4)=2, f(2)=1

Comment: You have rediscovered the Collatz conjecture: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla I just want to sleep, do you have a solution to this? My assignment is due for tomorrow. Please

Comment: If is your assignment, you've been joked. No solution is known.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla what the hell? are you sure? Why would my prof do something like that? Are you sure?

Comment: I can't decide if this is true or not.

Comment: @JerryTaylor: Tell your prof. that you stayed up all night and skipped other classes trying to prove it and you were not able to. See how she reacts.

Comment: I have a proof, but it won't fit in the margin.

Comment: @JerryTaylor, read the link of my first comment.

Comment: @JerryTaylor Better yet, tell your prof. that you stayed up all night, and you found the assignment slightly harder than previous assignments, but you finally finished it. Then plunk down a notebook containing 100 pages of cramped, totally illegible handwriting, with an excited "= 1 QED!" at the end.

Comment: @ChrisCulter why waste paper?

Comment: @Aditya Good point, sort through your trash and scrawl on the backs of junk mail envelopes and coffee-stained napkins instead. It'll be even more authentic!

Comment: Now, is it right?

Answer (score 1):

You are given a starting value $x_0\in{\mathbb N}$ and consider the integer sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq0}$ recursively defined by
$$x_{n+1}:=f(x_n)\qquad(n\geq0)\ .$$
It is impossible that this sequence converges to $1$, because this would enforce $x_n=1$ for all large $n$, whereas $f(1)=4$.